# DX: Unlocked Package - override packaged formula field locally, but keep packaging the "original" formula field

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, package-dependency

#### Package description

I am trying to create an unlocked package (e.g. `package1`), which adds multiple formula fields to the Opportunity object. Part of those formulas calculate the Opportunity's Revenue Period start/end dates.
To calculate those dates, we need *RevenueStartDate* and *RevenueDurationMonths* values defined on the Opportunity record.

I decided to have `RevStartDate__c` and `RevDurationMonths__c` packaged formula fields as "adapters" to the end user's org business rules - so, after the `package1` is installed to the org, they could modify these "adapter" field formulas according to how they define the revenue period.
To avoid dependencies on custom configuration/fields, I would like the packaged formula fields to refer only to standard Opp fields or constants, e.g.

```json
RevStartDate__c = Oppty.CloseDate
RevDurationMonths__c = 12
```

#### Local override in Opp.RevDurationMonths__c formula

During the development/debugging, I created an `Oppty.DurationMonths__c` **unpackaged** custom field to allow manually adjusting the duration for Opportunities in my scratch org.
This is similar to how the end user's org could be adjusting the packaged `Oppty.RevDurationMonths__c` formula to "wire" package to their business rules, or already existing fields.
So, in the scratch org, my local formulas are like below:

```json
RevStartDate__c = Oppty.CloseDate
RevDurationMonths__c = Oppty.DurationMonths__c    // local override
```

#### The problem

Since I have modified the packaged `Oppty.RevDurationMonths__c` in the org, this change will eventually get pulled from the scratch org into the `package1` packaging directory, and will overwrite the "harcoded" `Oppty.RevDurationMonths__c = 12` formula.

But this is what I would like to avoid - the goal is that the packaged field should **keep using the `RevDurationMonths__c = 12` constant when I create `package1` versions**, so that the packaged field has no dependencies on the org's custom configs.

#### Workaround that I've tried

I tried to adjust the `.forceignore` file to have the `package1/**/RevDurationMonths__c*` ignore pattern so that the updated custom field does not get pulled into the `package1/` directory.
At the same time, I added same field with local override as the `unpackaged/objects/Opportunity/fields/RevDurationMonths__c.field-meta.xml` file.

This way, when I push/pull changes, the `package1/objects/Opportunity/fields/RevDurationMonths__c.field-meta.xml` remains untouched (since it is ignored in `.forceignore`), and scratch org changes rather go into the `unpackaged/` directory.

The problem is that when I try to create a package version, the `package1/..../RevDurationMonths__c` custom field is ignored too - and packaging fails (since other formula fields depend on the `Oppty.RevDurationMonths__c` field).

### Question

Is there a way to make that local override for the formula field in the scratch org, but to keep packaging the "original version" of the field?
I would really like to avoid writing some complex batch jobs to overwrite this field with the "original version" during the packaging and then put back the "overriden" version.